# sudo logs date with user's locale, apparently. How do I make it use "C" locale?

Tags: logging, sudo, localization

I have sudo set to log to /var/log/sudo.log.  I've noticed that when the locale was set to "de_DE.UTF-8", it logged a localized date ("Mär" for "März") instead of "C" locale ("Mar" for "March").

How do I make it log the date independent of the user's locale?  Where the **** is that documented, anyway?

Or am I halluzinating?  (Could be, since I've got a major cold... ;-))

Answer (score 0):

Try creating an alias:

```
alias sudo='LANG=C sudo LANG='
```